# Broadcasting own IP across entire network

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, broadcast

I am wondering if there is a simpler way to broadcast my own IP to all devices on my network on a specific port using C or C++

I don't know too much about socket programming just cause most of my applications don't need a network.  I looked into it and [I found one piece of code](http://www.splinter.com.au/sending-a-udp-broadcast-packet-in-c-objective/) that looks promising although it doesn't exactly *broadcast* since it sends to specific IP addresses.

Is there a way to broadcast to addresses say between 192.168.1.0/255 in one fell swoop or do I need to go through loop through the addresses and then send a packet to them myself?

EDIT: I'm asking about c++ implementation, not network infrastructure.  That is why I linked the above link.

Comment: Yes, broadcasting is built into the TCP/IP stack, you should have found thousands of examples if you just searched a little.

Comment: I did, I didn't find much.  Care to be a little more specific on what to search for b/c I guess I didn't search for the right thing

Comment: When I searched, [this link](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_MessageAddressingandTransmissionMethodsUnicastBroa.htm) was one of the first that came up. I searched for the terms *tcp broadcast* (but note that broadcasting is not supported using TCP, it's really unicast only but you can accomplish the same using *multicast*).

Comment: ....okay.  I learned I'll just use UDP then.  Thx for the help

Comment: Looping through all the possible IP addresses on the LAN wouldn't be much fun on a class A network :)

Comment: Oh man that looks freaky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Send a UDP datagram to the broadcast address of the network. The UDP datagram will contain the origin IP address. Other apps in the network can obtain "your" IP address from the UDP datagram.

*Is there a way to broadcast to addresses say between 192.168.1.0/255 in one fell swoop or do I need to go through loop through the addresses and then send a packet to them myself?*

In every IP network there is an address, known as *broadcast address*, to which all devices in a network are enabled to receive datagrams. Further information can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

*I'm asking about c++ implementation, not network infrastructure. That is why I linked the above link.*

This example might be helpful:
https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/417/notes/sockets/udp.html

Comment: Thanks! You seem to be the only one that understood the issue.

Comment: Note : Sending to broadcast address might often need CAP_NET_ADMIN (or atleast CAP_NET_BROADCAST) capabilities (normally super user - but possible to set perms using sudo). And as @Baqs already pointed above - it'd be possible for UDP only.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much what IP [**multicast**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast) was invented for.

#### Edit 0:

Ton of examples on the internet. Just a couple for you:

- [using boost asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html),
- [using plain sockets in C](http://ganges.cs.tcd.ie/undergrad/4ba2/multicast/antony/example.html).

Many more out there, but if you are any serious about doing network programming, get [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) and you'll never regret.

Comment: I'm more so asking about implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do much network programming without understanding at least *some* of its infrastructure.